# How to know if a node script is run directly or included?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = 'foo';
```

I'm trying to add, at the bottom:

```
if(is run as shell script){
    console.log(module.exports);
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this?  I can hack something together using things like `process.argv` and `__filename`, but is that the best way?